# JsTree how to create a root node

Tags: javascript, jstree

How to create a root node using 'create' method

```
Root
 |___ Child1
 |___ Child2
```

I am using JsTree, by using 'json_data' I can able to create nodes, but I want to create all nodes dynamically using 'create' method.

Please help me....

Answer (score 11):

As of version 3.0.0-beta10 of jsTree, to create a top-level node, the reference for the parent is `"#"`.  For example:

```
$("#jstree").jstree('create_node', '#', {'id' : 'myId', 'text' : 'My Text'}, 'last');
```

The older answer given here didn't work with that version of jsTree.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is what you are looking for:

```
$("#tree").jstree("create", -1, false, "Name", false, true);
```